# How independent should Django apps be from one another?

Tags: django, django-models

I'm having trouble determining how I should split up the functions of my project into different apps.

Simple example: We have members, and members can have one more more services. Services can be upgraded, downgraded, other services added on, and can also be cancelled. (This is extremely simplfied, were it that simple in reality I'd use a pre-made solution)

My first thought was to make this into a 'member' application, and then a 'services' app that takes care of renewals, up/downgrades and cancellations.

I then thought I should probably make a renewal app, an up/downgrade app, and a cancellation app. But, these apps would all depend on the same table(s) in the DB (members and services). I thought applications were supposed to be independent from one another. Is it ok to make applications that are heavily dependent on other apps models?

Along the same lines, which application should I use to store the models to create the services table if so many apps use it?

Answer (score 3):

I think you first thought was right: you don't get so many benefits of splitting everythin into multiple apps, and on the contrary it could become messy and hard to mantain.

The Django way of doing things depends a lot of the models. Each object is mapped to an entity on the data model. Your apps are mostly organised in relation to such data model. So, if you have an entity (service) that has different pieces, it is better to understand such pieces as parts of the same thing. The other entity (member) should be another one since it is a different thing.

There is no penalty of importing models from different apps. The most important thing is anyway building data model to be consistent.

Answer (score 0):

The point of apps is to allow code which is intended to be reused as an addon by third parties. You probably won't want to split your projects up much, if at all into apps.